# Stuck on AppleScript to add password to PDF in Preview

Tags: applescript

trying to add a password to a PDF in AppleScript. The below code gets through

```
   click menu item 23 -- Export Menu item
```

but fails on the next line with an "invalid index" error "Can't get window 1..."

... and then guessing my next line for the checkbox will need something similar on the end.

Thanks in advance

Tim

```
set myFolder to path to desktop as string
set myFile to myFolder & "test.pdf"

tell application "Preview"
    open myFile
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Preview"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "File"
                tell menu "File"
                    click menu item 23 -- Export Menu item
                    click button "Permissions..."  of sheet 1 of window 1
                    click checkbox "Require Password To Open Document"
                    text field 1
                    keystroke "1234"
                    text field 2
                    keystroke "1234"
                    text field 3
                    keystroke "1234"
                    text field 4
                    keystroke "1234"
                    keystroke return
                    keystroke return
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Monterey**  with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is coded to check whether or not the **[] Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** *checkbox* is checked on the **System Preferences** >  **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** tab, as that would affect how one would programmatically navigate the various dialog boxes using the *tab key*. It's coded to then branch one way to the other to handle the state of that *checkbox*.

Here is an example of how I would *code* it:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property myPassword : "1234"

set myFolder to path to desktop as string
set myFile to myFolder & "test.pdf"

--  # Get the value of AppleKeyboardUIMode to determine if the
--  # 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'
--  # checkbox is checked on the System Preferences >  
--  # Keyboard > Shortcuts tab.

set keyboardNavigation to my checkAppleKeyboardUIMode()

--  # Open the target file in Preview.          

tell application "Preview"
    open myFile
    activate
end tell

--  # Use System Events to export the document 
--  # and navigate the ensuing dialog boxes. 

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Preview"
        
        tell its menu "File" of ¬
            menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 to ¬
            click (its first menu item whose name is "Export…")
        
        repeat until exists button "Permissions…" of sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        
        tell its sheet 1 of window 1 to click button "Permissions…"
        
        repeat until exists ¬
            checkbox "Require Password To Open Document" of ¬
            sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        
        tell its sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
            
            click checkbox "Require Password To Open Document"
            delay 0.1
            
            if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
                --  # Use keyboard navigation to move focus
                --  # between controls is not checked.
                key code 48 -- # tab key
                delay 0.1
                key code 48 -- # tab key
                delay 0.1
                keystroke myPassword
                delay 0.1
                key code 48 -- # tab key
                delay 0.1
                keystroke myPassword
                delay 0.1
                key code 48 -- # tab key
                delay 0.1
                keystroke myPassword
                delay 0.1
                key code 48 -- # tab key
                delay 0.1
                keystroke myPassword
            else
                --  # Use keyboard navigation to move
                --  # focus between controls is checked.            
                key code 48 -- # tab key                
                delay 0.1
                keystroke myPassword
                delay 0.1
                key code 48 -- # tab key                
                delay 0.1
                keystroke myPassword
                delay 0.1
                repeat 6 times
                    key code 48 -- # tab key
                    delay 0.1
                end repeat
                keystroke myPassword
                delay 0.1
                key code 48 -- # tab key                
                delay 0.1
                keystroke myPassword
            end if
            
            delay 0.1
            click button "Apply"
            delay 0.1
            
        end tell
        
        click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        if exists button "Replace" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 then ¬
            click button "Replace" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        
        click button 1 of window 1 -- # Close the document.
        
    end tell
end tell



--  ## Handler ##

on checkAppleKeyboardUIMode()
    
    --  # Get the fully qualified POSIX pathname of the target .plist file.
    
    set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        the POSIX path of ¬
            (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
        ".GlobalPreferences.plist"
    
    --  # Get the value of AppleKeyboardUIMode to determine if the
    --  # 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'
    --  # checkbox is checked on the System Preferences >  
    --  # Keyboard > Shortcuts tab.
    
    try
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
                return the value of ¬
                    the property list item "AppleKeyboardUIMode"
    on error
        return 0
    end try
    
end checkAppleKeyboardUIMode
```

---

**Notes:**

One of the issues in the *code* of the question was the use of three `.` instead of an ellipsis `…` in: `click button "Permissions..."`

Also, the remaining *code* would not have executed because it is wrapped in a `tell menu "File"` *statement*. The *example* **AppleScript** *code* presented herein focuses in the proper places for the *events* to take place when compared to how its coded in the question.

Note that **UI Scripting** is *kludgy* at best and prone to failure due to changes in the *hierarchical **UI element** structure* of the **OS** and or *application* being scripted and or timing issues where the use of the `delay` *command* may be necessary and or its *value* adjusted.

Case in point, I originally coded this to avoid using *tabbing* and *keystroking*, however it presented mixed results in that it worked sometimes and not other times, and why I recorded to do those very things. (**UI Scripting** Ugh!)

Also, as the first *dialog box* in the export process is not changing the *name* of the *document* or the *location* it is being saved, the password protected document may end up in a different *location* than from where it was opened. Additional coding required to modify that possible behavior.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: We have a winner! My undying gratitude to you, and all in these forums who take on these challenges.

Comment: @Tim G, I Modified the _code_ placing the check for the _value_ of the `AppleKeyboardUIMode` _key_  into a _handler_. I did this so if that setting has never they been toggled it will trap the error and return `0` as it would be set if once turned on and then off again. I had forgot that this _key_ doesn't exist by default. Sorry for any confusion.